# How to post multiple object data with socket.io in express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I managde to post singel data with socket.io, but if i add another(timestamp) then its showing nothing.

app.js

```
app.post('/update', function(req, res, next){
    io.sockets.emit("update", req.body);
    io.sockets.emit("update", Date.now());
    res.send({});
});
```

add_users.jade

```
    script(src='jquery-1.7.1.js')
    script(src='http://localhost:3002/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script(type='text/javascript')
        var socket;
        socket =  io.connect('http://localhost:3002'); 
        socket.on('update', function(newUserAdded, time) {
            console.log("update: ", newUserAdded + "update: ", time)
        });
        $(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $.post("/update", {
                    newUserAdded: $("input").val(),
                    time: getTime()
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `(new Date).getTime()`

Comment: Thanks, silly me lol it worked. But it's giving strange numbers "1343719031833", what is that?

Comment: Milliseconds since epoch, 1/1/1970. You want to use a function like toLocaleTimeString() if you want something human readable.